# Template Haskell and Implicit Parameters

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, implicit-parameters

Is there a way to create functions with implicit parameters or let bindings with implicit parameters using template haskell?

I.e. is it possible to generate a signature like this using template haskell:

```
 doSomething :: (?context :: Context) => m a
```

Or an invocation like this:

```
 invoc = let ?context = newContext in doSomething
```

I could not find suitable algebraic data types nor any functions which would help me out on this topic in the [API documentation for template haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/libraries/template-haskell-2.7.0.0/Language-Haskell-TH.html). I'm using GHC 7.4.2.

If there is no native support for this extension in template haskell, is there some other possibility to inject code during compilation (maybe something like a general “code injection function” within template haskell?).

***EDIT:*** I tried the suggestion from the comments, this is what happens:

```
runQ [d| f :: (?c :: String) => Int ; f = 7 |]

<interactive>:10:17: parse error on input `c'
```

whereas this works:

```
 runQ [d| f :: Int ; f = 7|]
 [SigD f_0 (ConT GHC.Types.Int),ValD (VarP f_0) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL 7))) []]
```

doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: Did you try quoting an expression using implicit parameters and seeing what AST you get?

Comment: Thanks, did not think about that; anyway it throws an error (see edited question). Does not seem to work.

Comment: Implicit parameters seems to have fallen out of the corpus of modern haskell idioms -- I'm not surprised if TH never got support for it.

Comment: @scravy: Yeah, if the quotation causes an error (make sure you have the extension enabled in all relevant modules, of course) that seems like a very good indication that it's not supported at all.

Comment: Also, just below the definition of the `Exp` type in the `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax` module, there is [a comment which says "omitted: implicit parameters"](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/libraries/template-haskell-2.7.0.0/src/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#line-879).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way that's pretty fragile, but sort of works. While you can't refer
to ?x in the Exp that template haskell uses, you can refer to a definition in
another module like:

```
reserved_prefix_x = ?x
```

Below is some code that generates variables like above in one run of ghc,
and in a second run of ghc the variables actually refer to implicit parameters.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
module GenMod (h) where

import Data.Generics
import Data.IORef
import Data.List
import Language.Haskell.Meta.Parse as P
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Language.Haskell.Exts.QQ as Q
import System.IO.Unsafe

h = Q.hs { quoteExp = \s -> do
    r <- either fail (upVars . return) (P.parseExp s)
    writeMod'
    return r
    }

pfx = "q_"

{-# NOINLINE vars #-}
vars :: IORef (S.Set String)
vars = unsafePerformIO (newIORef S.empty)

writeMod' = runIO $ writeFile "GEN.hs" . ppMod =<< readIORef vars

writeMod = -- might be needed to avoid multiple calls to writeFile?
           -- in this example this is called for every use of `h'
    QuasiQuoter { quoteDec = \ _ -> do
                    writeMod'
                    [d| _ = () |] }

ppMod xs = "{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction, ImplicitParams #-}\n\
            \module GEN where\n" ++
    unlines (map (\x -> pfx ++ x ++ " = ?" ++ x) (S.toList xs))

upVars x = do
    x' <- x
    runIO $ modifyIORef vars (S.union (getMatchingVars x'))
    runIO $ print =<< readIORef vars
    return x'

getMatchingVars =
    everything
        S.union
        (mkQ S.empty
            (\ (OccName x) -> maybe S.empty S.singleton (stripPrefix pfx x)))
```

A Main.hs file that uses the quasiquoter GenMod.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction, ImplicitParams, QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, CPP #-}
import GenMod

#ifndef stage1
import GEN
#endif

f_ = [h| q_hithere |]
```

You have to call ghc twice, like:

```
ghci -Dstage1 Main.hs
GHCi, version 7.6.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 2] Compiling GenMod           ( GenMod.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Ex.hs, interpreted )
fromList ["hithere"]

Ex.hs:8:6: Not in scope: `q_hithere'
Failed, modules loaded: GenMod.
```

Though ghc fails, it still generates the GEN.hs which contains:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction, ImplicitParams #-}
module GEN where
q_hithere = ?hithere
```

Which will be there when you load Main (leaving out the -D flag)

```
*Main> :t f_
f_ :: (?hithere::t) => t
```

This kind of trouble probably isn't worth it. Maybe other situations of calling out to other programs from TH are more motivating such as inline calls to other languages http://hpaste.org/50837 (gfortran example)

Since I used haskell-src-meta's default parser, the quasiquote gets to use variables "reserved_prefix_x" not "?x". It should be possible to accept the "?x" without too much difficulty.